# How can I share my connection on Windows 8.1 to VMware Linux Ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows-8, vmware

I trying to share my cable connection on Windows 8.1 with a VMware Linux Ubuntu, but this doesn't works.

The Linux just stay trying to connect but without a success.

This is my Virtual Network Editor:

Host-only

[image]

NAT

[image]

IPConfig on Windows:

[image]

Someone knows what can I do in this case?

Comment: I have good results using the bridged setting with VM's. Have you tried that?

Comment: I was recieving the message "Cannot change network to bridged: There are no un-bridged host network adapters." when I tried to create a bridge connection, but now I restored default the Virtual Networks and I have a bridge connection and this works fine!! Thank you!

Comment: Try using the bridged setting.

Comment: I'm glad that worked. Please upvote/accept the answer that worked for you so that others in need can find it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to user a bridge connection!

[image]

And disable my firewall for VMWare:

"Allow all traffic to / from virtual machines supported by the firewall"

[image]